# Query creation in Spring Data - dynamic where clause

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way in Spring data to dynamically form the where clause?

What I want to do is have a method (which is like the findBy / get method) which runs a WHERE and AND using the mentioned properties which are NOT NULL.

For example,

```
Consider the object Person [firstName, lastName, age, gender]
```

Our method looks something like this

```
findBy_IfNotNullFirstName_AndIfNotNullLastName_AndIfNotNullAge_AndIfNotNullGender(String firstName, String lastName, Integer age, String gender)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at JPA Specification and Predicate, and Even better QueryDSL, there both supported by spring data repositories. 
This article provide an example:
http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: Yes. Specifications is what i had been looking for. "Specifically": We can use the Predicate javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder.and(Predicate... restrictions) method to bundle predicates and build a Specification which we can supply to a Repository findAll.

Answer (score 17):

A simpler option is to test if the parameter is null right in the JPQL query:

Exemple from my project:

```
@Query("select m from MessageEntity m " +
            "join fetch m.demandeAnalyseEntities d " +
            "where (:patientId is null or d.noPtn= :patientId) " +
            " and " +
            " ( :labNbr is null or d.noLab= :labNbr) " +
            " and " +
            " ( :reqDate is null or d.dteReq= :reqDate) " +
            " and " +
            " ( :reqNum is null or d.noReq= :reqNum) "
    )
    List<MessageEntity> findMessagesWithDemandesOnly(@Param("patientId") Long pid,
                                                     @Param("labNbr") Integer labNo,
                                                     @Param("reqDate") String reqDate,
                                                     @Param("reqNum") Integer reqNum,
                                                     Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: You can extend your JPA repo interface **using custom fragment interfaces**.

1. Define your custom methods on a new interface

   ```java
   public interface PersonFragRepository {
       List<User> findPersonByWhatever(
           String firstName, String lastName, String age, String gender);
   }
   ```
2. Provide the implementation

   ```java
   public class PersonFragRepositoryImpl implements PersonFragRepository {
       @PersistenceContext
       private EntityManager entityManager;

       @Override
       List<User> findPersonByWhatever(
           String firstName, String lastName, String age, String gender) {
          ...
       }
   }
   ```
3. Extends your JPA interface

   ```java
   public interface PersonRepository
       extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer>, PersonFragRepository
   ```