# Spring data jpa Query dynamically pass where clause

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, lucene, spring-data-jpa

My Entity is in this way

```
public class event
    {
        String title;

        String description;

        String city;
    }
```

I am new to Spring data jpa ,i want implement search feature when an user enters "Hello Hyderabad Fest"
I want token size the string and split into words and find Any word matches on any properties on entity with search query hit to db.

> WHERE title LIKE '%Hello%' OR title LIKE '%Hyderabad%' OR title LIKE
>   '%Fest%' OR description LIKE '%Hello%' OR description LIKE
>   '%Hyderabad%' OR description LIKE '%Fest%'city LIKE '%Hello%' OR
>   cityitle LIKE '%Hyderabad%' OR city LIKE '%Fest%'

How can we achieve this in spring data jpa.

1. Can we dynamically pass where condition in Spring data jpa named queries
2. Can we  lucene kind query which we use in nosql dbs.
3. any other suggestion

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query creation in Spring Data - dynamic where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482339/query-creation-in-spring-data-dynamic-where-clause)

Comment: Could please share some examples

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql fulltext search query solved the above issue http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/